# How to use Junos PyEZ configuration table to extract all interface units?

Tags: python, pyez

I was trying to use PyEZ InterfaceTable to extract interface configuration. My problem is that I can only see one unit per interface while there are actually more than one configured on some interfaces.

The script

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
from jnpr.junos.resources.interface import InterfaceTable

with Device(host=HOST_TEST, user='lab', passwd='lab123') as dev:
    tabl = InterfaceTable(dev)
    tabl.get()

    print(tabl.keys())
    print(tabl['ge-0/0/4'].unit_name)
```

In my case I have 2 units on ge-0/0/4 interface

```
lab@srx# show interfaces ge-0/0/4  
vlan-tagging;
unit 108 {
    vlan-id 108;
    family inet {
        address 172.20.108.1/24;
    }
}
unit 109 {
    vlan-id 109;
    family inet {
        address 172.20.109.1/24;
    }
}
```

But the result is only giving me one unit (in 2nd line of this output):

```
['ge-0/0/0', 'ge-0/0/1', 'ge-0/0/2', 'ge-0/0/3', 'ge-0/0/4', 'lo0']
108
```

Ideally, I would like to work with all units and with some confuguration options under each unit (such as family and address).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer "user defined tables" example at https://github.com/vnitinv/pyez-examples/blob/master/9_user_defined_table.py

Comment: You need to identify an appropriate RPC for the config hierarchy you would like to process. You can do this by adding ```| display xml rpc```

Comment: I was asking about configuration (get/set) tables and your example is for op (rpc) table. If you could provide an example of config table that will allow to configure many interfaces AND units at the same time, that would be great.

Comment: I understand the requirement, will get back by tomorrow